# Trying to understand Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

$Ax = b$

Here $A$ is a matrix, $x$ and $b$ can be a vector or matrices. The intuition behind this equation is that $A$ is a linear function which takes an input $x$ and gives an output $b$.

[Diagram for $Ax = b$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx6X7.png)

So my question is if I know the output and linear function I can solve for $X$ which can be done by inverting $A$. On the other hand, If i try to estimate the function with known input and output, it becomes linear regression? Is that difference between solving system of equations and linear regression? or am I making a mistake thinking this way?

Comment: Depending on the situation, $A$ may not be invertible. If $A$ is not surjective, then linear regression is finding an $x$ so that $Ax$ is as close to $b$ as possible.

Comment: Typically, solving $Ax=b$ for $A$ is not an *overdetermined* problem (where regression/least squares/etc. come into play) but rather an *underdetermined* problem. That is, there are many exact solutions and it is not clear how to pick one. For a toy example, $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has solutions given by all $2 \times 2$ matrices whose first column is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: there are usually going to be many matrices $A$ with $Ax=b$. The only exception is when $x=0$ or when $x$ has dimension $1$, or $b$ has dimension $0$:

Comment: That makes sense now. @Ian. Thank you.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling $A$ is a known, not an unknown in this problem.  $x$ is the only unknown, so the fact that there exist multiple $A$ is completely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I think you didn't read all the way @JMoravitz